# How to create a multidimensional array or object from a single array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have been struggling with this for the last two hours and still can not find a solution (maybe I am blocked!!).

I will start with how the result/output should looks like and is as follow:

```
results = [
  'result_1' => [
      "col_1" => "asc",
      "col_2" => "asc",
      "col_3" => "asc"
  ]
];
```

This is how I am doing it so far:

```
var ls_sort_keys = [];
var ls_settings = {};
var ls_report_name = "<?php echo $report_name ?>";

<?php foreach ($header_array as $key => $value) { ?>
   ls_sort_keys.push("<?php echo $value; ?>");
<?php } ?>

ls_settings[ls_report_name] = {
    $.each(ls_sort_keys, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key, value);
    });
}
```

The result of `console.log(ls_sort_keys)` is an array of three values containing `["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]`.

I am getting the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` in this line `$.each(ls_sort_keys, function (key, value)` and my guess is because is not allowed such thing in there.

Having said that, how I can transform the result into the output? The output is shown as an array but could be a Javascript object since it will be stored in the localStorage and AFAIK it does not support array but only strings.

Comment: Your PHP loop runs server-side, I do not see how it can be running the Javscript `push()`. (Except that last one)

Comment: Try assigning it to a property something like `{ items: $.each(...) }`

Comment: Your desired result is invalid JavaScript. Also you cannot say `console.log` outputs something when you also say you have a syntax error. It cannot be both. This question lacks information needed to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: @KevinBoucher what do you mean? Doing `console.log(ls_sort_keys)` I am able to see an array of three elements which is the expected result there. I am not following you.

Comment: He means that invoking a function inside an object literal without assigning it is invalid js

Comment: @trincot I never said it's a valid Javascript result, I use "notepad" (lol) to build that output and yes, there is a problem on the text which I will fix, that `console.log` should be for `ls_sort_keys` thanks for catch up this

Comment: Where is the "asc" coming from? Is it a value of something in PHP?

Comment: @trincot that is a default value that can be hard coded, it will change later on based on user input/action.

Comment: @ReynierPM, ah I think I see now. Your loop outputs a succession of ls_sort_keys.push() calls that re subsequently processed on the client side.

Comment: OK, @RenierPM, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final loop should indeed create an object. But the opening `{` will be interpreted as the start of an object literal, but then you go on as if it is the opening of a *code block*. This is invalid syntax.

Instead you can use `Object.assign`, computed property syntax and spread syntax, like this:

```
ls_settings[ls_report_name] = Object.assign(
    ...ls_sort_keys.map(col => ({ [col]: "asc" }))
)
```

Demo stripped from PHP code:

```js
var ls_sort_keys = [];
var ls_settings = {};
var ls_report_name = "report_1";

ls_sort_keys.push("col_1", "col_2", "col_3");

ls_settings[ls_report_name] = Object.assign(
    ...ls_sort_keys.map(col => ({ [col]: "asc" }))
)

console.log(ls_settings);
```

Or, if you prefer a more old-fashioned syntax:

```js
var ls_sort_keys = [];
var ls_settings = {};
var ls_report_name = "report_1";

ls_sort_keys.push("col_1", "col_2", "col_3");

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ls_sort_keys.length; i++) {
    obj[ls_sort_keys[i]] = "asc";
}

ls_settings[ls_report_name] = obj;

console.log(ls_settings);
```